# recursive cte query | Creating multiple numbered rows | Sql-server

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm trying to complete a column in a table with fields from a number 0900000000000000000000000007165 
to number 0900000000000000000000000008165

I have a problem that these are too big numbers for this piece of code, I have no idea what to do with it

Type:
Id - varchar(31)

Error: (translate)

> Msg 240, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Type mismatch between the anchor and the cyclic part in the "start" column of the cyclic "cter" query.

```
  with cter as (
     select 0900000000000000000000000007165 as start, 0900000000000000000000000008165 as loop_end
     union all
     select c.start + 1, loop_end
     from cter c
     where c.start < loop_end
)

INSERT INTO [Base].[dbo].[Table] (Id)
   select c.start
   from cter c
   option (maxrecursion 0);
```

Comment: What is the data type of id?

Comment: Any reason why you not just loop from 7165 to 8165 and concat the result to your 090000000000000000000000000 afterwards?

Comment: I'd, personally, suggest a tally too; they are *way* faster than an rCTE for this kind of thing.

Comment: @forpas Id - varchar(31)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is actually as the error suggests, the data types of the top part of the recursive CTE, and the bottom part differ:

```
SELECT [name],system_type_name
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set('select 0900000000000000000000000007165 as start, 0900000000000000000000000008165 as loop_end',NULL,NULL);
```

This gives you `numeric(30,0)` for both values. On the other hand if you check the bottom part you get different results:

```
SELECT [name],system_type_name
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set('SELECT sq.start +1 AS Start, sq.loop_end FROM(select 0900000000000000000000000007165 as start, 0900000000000000000000000008165 as loop_end) sq',NULL,NULL);
```

Here, `Start` has a datatype of `numeric(31,0)`, which is **different** from the top level.

But, to expand on my comment, you'd be better off with a Tally here. That'll actually completely avoid the error, as there's no recursive CTE, and is far faster:

```
DECLARE @Start numeric(30,0),
        @End numeric(30,0);

SET @Start = 0900000000000000000000000007165;
SET @End = 0900000000000000000000000008165;

WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP (CONVERT(bigint,@End - @Start))
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4) --This will produce up 10,000 rows. CROSS JOIN to N more for more rows.
INSERT INTO Base.dbo.[Table] (ID)
SELECT RIGHT(CONCAT(REPLICATE('0',31),T.I + @Start),31)
FROM Tally T;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was originally trying with BIGINT and got arithmetic overflow error. Later, modified with NUMBERIC(30,0), Thanks to Larnu. I am able to get proper result.

```sql
DECLARE @loop_start CHAR(31) = '0900000000000000000000000007165'
, @loop_end CHAR(31) = '0900000000000000000000000008165'
;with cter as 
(
     select CAST(@loop_start as numeric(30,0)) as start, CAST(@loop_end as numeric(30,0)) loop_end
     union all
     select cast((c.start +1) as numeric(30,0)) , cast(loop_end as numeric(30,0))
     from cter c
     where c.start < loop_end
)

   select  c.start
   from cter c
   option (maxrecursion 0);
```

**The result set is:**

```
+---------------------------------+
| 900000000000000000000000007165 |
| 900000000000000000000000007166 |
|                               . |
|                               . |
|                               . |
| 900000000000000000000000008163 |
| 900000000000000000000000008164 |
| 900000000000000000000000008165 |
+---------------------------------+
```

Comment: *"You will get arithmetic overflow error , as this value is too big even for bigint datatype."* not true. `'0900000000000000000000000007165'` will be interpreted as a `numeric(30,0)`: `SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set('select 0900000000000000000000000007165 as start, 0900000000000000000000000008165 as loop_end',NULL,NULL)`

Comment: sorry. I did not think of NUMERIC. thanks. I have corrected the answer.